# Django best practice for web service

Tags: django

I want to create a webservice in a django project.
What i mean by webservice is a route which will talk with json structures instead of html.
I am wondering if a show put the webservice code in views.py or if i should create a separate file (like api.py ?). It will work on both cases, i juste want to know which is the cleanest way

Comment: is it for public use, or for some back-end communication between trusted servers? If the last, then consider *not* using REST because of the overhead and such. Use sockets or a message-system like zeroMQ instead.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you want to build a web API for your application.

There are two dominant third party plugins for django

- Django Rest Framework. - http://www.django-rest-framework.org/
- Tastypi - http://tastypieapi.org/

Both have there pros and cons. Do some research and choose the one that best suites for your need.